# (Pascal) Read and use a variable one number/character at the time

Tags: converters, pascal, radix

I'm working on a project but I've gotten stuck. I need to make a Pascal program capable of converting a number of any base (2-16) to decimal (10). My problem however is that **I can't use things like array/string/readkey/type, etc.** Basically I'm stuck with **only the most basic functions like repeat/while/for/if/case, etc.** My problem arises from how I need to input the variable. It needs to be:

> -"base:number."
>
> -"answer in base 10"

For example

> -16:123.
>
> -291

I can't separate the base from the number using ":". I'm also not sure of how to separate the numbers. I thought about using Ord which seems to be the only way but I have no idea where to put it, or how to write it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need arrays or any of that stuff. The exercise wants you to apply knowledge of two things: how to process input one character at a time, recognizing semaphores (the colon ':'), and understanding of how the digits of a number are related to its base.

The radix of a number is not an intrinsic quality of a number -- a 7 is a 7 is a 7 no matter what radix you represent it in. The radix is a *textual*, human-readable characteristic of a number. You have already learned how to handle polynomials in school:

```
567 → 5×10² + 6×10¹ + 7×10⁰
```

That 10 in there is the radix → base 10. If we were to use hexadecimal (base 16) the radix is 16:

```
567₁₆ → 5×16² + 6×16¹ + 7×16⁰
```

The final trick is to understand how to compose and decompose numbers using the radix via multiplication and remainder operations. Let's rewrite that polynomial to make it more obvious:

```
567₁₆ → 5×16×16 + 6×16 + 7×1
```

That five is there in the third-from-the-right position because we multiplied it by 16 **two** times. The 6 is in the second-from-the-right position because we multiplied it by 16 **one** time. And the 7 is in the rightmost position because we multiplied it by 16 **zero** times. In code, that's:

```
n := 0;
n := n * 16 + 5;
n := n * 16 + 6;
n := n * 16 + 7;
writeln( 'n = ', n );
```

For your specific assignment, the first number (before the colon ':') is always in base 10. The second number (after the colon ':') uses the radix given by the first number.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand. 
I do know how to change bases, yes. I just don't know how to separate the input so I can do so in Pascal. That's what I'm having trouble with.
>"the first number (before the colon ':') is always in base 10."
The very first number is not supposed to use any base. It's supposed to dictate the base for the number after the colon.

Comment: A number is always **expressed** in a base. The part before the colon (the base) is indeed always expressed in base 10. So read it as such, digit by digit, until you find a colon. Then use that base to decode the rest of the line. The answer looks correct to me.